# How do I print GC.stat from Rails/Unicorn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, garbage-collection, profiling, unicorn

We are using Unicorn to run Rails4 on Ruby2.0.

We configured Unicorn to force a garbage-collection between each request:

```
In Rails, config.ru:
if defined? Unicorn
  GC_FREQUENCY = 1
  require_dependency 'unicorn/oob_gc'
  GC.disable # Don't run GC during requests
  use Unicorn::OobGC, GC_FREQUENCY # Force GC once every GC_FREQUENCY requests
end
```

Is there a way I can print `GC.stat` or `GC::Profiler.report` before each collection?